# Increase scan rate autotest with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, rspec, growl

I find the integration with RSpec, Growl and rails particularly useful. However, it takes about two to three seconds before a change (save file) is picked up by autotest.

Is there a way to increase the interval by which autotest scans for filechanges?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac OS X then you can try [autotest-fsevent](http://github.com/svoop/autotest-fsevent) or [autotest-inotify](http://github.com/ewollesen/autotest-inotify) if you are on Linux. They will replace the standard Autotest filesystem polling to instead listen to events from the OS.

Comment: I have installed autotest-fsevent as I'm on a Mac, but it does not seem to make a difference. There is a 3 second gap between the "save" and the running of the tests in the adjusted spec. I have verified this manually by having both textmate and activity monitor next to each other. 

Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Did you add require 'autotest/fsevent' after all other requires in your ~/.autotest file?

Comment: yep, but my ~/.autotest is rather empty. This is what I have in it:
require 'autotest/growl'
require 'autotest/fsevent'
BTW: I'm also running spork, but that does not seem to make much difference

Comment: One of those seconds comes from the 1.0s latency in http://github.com/svoop/autotest-fsevent/blob/master/ext/fsevent/fsevent_sleep.c

Comment: Well, how long does it take on average on your machine? I'm on a fairly quick macbook pro 2.4GHz

Comment: And another one from http://github.com/svoop/autotest-fsevent/blob/master/lib/autotest/fsevent.rb Kernel.sleep `self.sleep`. I suggest trying to change both of those to something low like 0.1 but not 0.

Comment: I'm on an old Linux box and right now not even using autotest. The speed of the machine should have very little to do with it.

Comment: Ok, not quite sure how to apply the changes; have to admit that I've only recently made the switch to Ruby (coming from .Net)

Comment: I understand. This is not changes one usually should have to make. The change of fsevent.rb is simple. Run `gem environment` to see where the gem files are and then fire up your text editor and change self.sleep to 0.1. The C code change is a bit trickier because you have to recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spork? Spork is a separate server that you can load Rails into for your test suite.  [Michael Hart's book](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec%3aspork) shows you how to set it up.

Comment: Yes, I'm using spork (actually I'm following Michheal's tutorial to the letter). Having spork run in the background does not make a difference.